# Loading paypal's x509 public certificate from file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, paypal

I am using website payments standard provided by paypal. I have generated the code for paypal pay now button. I have generated a key and certificate pair for my application and also have uploaded my application certificate to paypal and retrieved their public certificate as well as the cert id for my application certificate.

Using the paypal public certificate and the cert id I am attempting to encrypt data sent to paypal and then sign in it using my private key. The entire code for application is written in ruby on rails. But for some reason I always keep getting "Cannot decrypt cert id" when I try to make a payment. On investigation I found out that the error is in this line of code

```
OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new File.read("paypal-public.pem");
```

This line throws a nested ASN1 error.

According to another stackoverflow question I tried adding \n to the end of the .pem file but to no avail.

Any assistance with this regards will be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance.